# rxjs subscribe to function - wait for event

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
runThisFunction.subscribe();
```

In this function - I have to 2 scenarios.  One that returns an observable immediately and after it shows a modal and user clicks ok - then send the observable.  My issue is I can return immediately without any problem, but how do I delay sending the obvservable until user clicks ok?
I am getting an error that subscribe of undefined.

```
runThisFunction() { //This is what I have and it returns fine.  How do I do the same but after a modal event?
   let result = new Observable(observable => observable.next(data));

   return result;
}
```

Comment: Well, the function runThisFunction has to be called. That is, you'll have to do "runThisFunction()" instead of just "runThisFunction". "runThisFunction" is the method reference, not a method call.

Answer (score 1):

Try below;

- Define a `Subject` say `processConfirmedSubject$`. Subject do not emit unless we call `next()` function on the `Subject`
- Define a function to trigger the `processConfirmedSubject$`. This function will simply contain `processConfirmedSubject$.next()`
- Assign `runThisFunction()` to a variable say `myFunction$`
- combine the two values using `combineLatest` from `rxjs`
- subscribe to the combined Observable

At the end you should have something like

```
processConfirmedSubject$ = new Subject();
processConfirmed$ = this.processConfirmedSubject$.asObservable();
confirmAction() {
  this.processConfirmedSubject$.next();
}
myFunction$ = runThisFunction();
combinedFunction$ = combineLatest([this.myFunction$, this.processConfirmed$]).pipe(
  map(([myFunction]) => myFunction)
)

ngOnInit() {
  combinedFunction$.subscribe()
}
```

With the above, whenever you call the function `confirmAction()` the observable reevaluates acting like a confirm dialogue